# Finding algebraic curve satisfying given parameterization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, parametric

Is there an easy way to find an algebraic curve that satisfies a given parameterization?  Specifically, I am talking about the following parameterization: $$ x=z(1-z),\hspace{10pt} y=\sum_{n=1}^r \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (z-1)^n, \hspace{10pt} z \in \mathbb{C}$$

What might make the above easier is that $\sum_{n=1}^r \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} (z-1)^n$ is the truncation of the Taylor expansion of $log(z)$ around $z=1$.  And so, when we take the limit $r \to \infty$ the unknown curve should be:
$$ 1-e^y-xe^{-y}=0$$

Is it a matter of playing around until you find something?  Or, is there some useful techniques?

Thank you.

Comment: In this case, you have a 1 dimensional curve in 3 dimensional space.  A parametric equation is usually the best way to represent that.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified.  z is complex.  x and y are meromorphic functions on the compact Riemann sphere.  For my purposes I need an actual equation the parametric equations satisfy... unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is called [implicitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation#Implicitization) and can be solved systematically but not easily by hand.

In Mathematica (and Wolfram Alpha), you can use [`Eliminate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eliminate.html).

For $n=2$, `Eliminate[{x==z(1-z), y==(z-1)-(z-1)^2/2}, {z}]` gives
$$
(6-4 x) y+4 y^2 = (-x-6) x
$$

For $n=3$, `Eliminate[{x==z(1-z), y==(z-1)-(z-1)^2/2+(z-1)^3/3}, {z}]` gives
$$
(-36 y-66) y = 4 x^3-9 x^2+x (66-72 y)
$$